# rxjs filter does not return anything in false condition

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I had made this code:

```
from(getState().servers)
.filter(server => server.apps.length == 0)
.take(1)
.mergeMap(element => element.length === 0 ? atLeastOneApp : of(element))
.mergeMap(server => of(server.key))
.subscribe(
    (key) =>  dispatch({
                type:ADD_APP,
                payload:{
                 key,
                 appName
                }
             }),
    (err) => console.log(err)
);


const atLeastOneApp = from(getState().servers)
.filter(server => server.apps.length == 1)
.take(1);
```

that needs to filter only elements with zero/one app running.
The problem is that at the first filter, if `server.apps.length`is different than zero,it does not produce any result (I'm expecting `null`, `undefined` or `[]`, trying to print on console but nothing changes).

How could I fix this code? I've tried also `takeWhile` operator but nothing change.

Thank you

Comment: This is very confusing. When `server.apps.length > 0` you want to map `server` to `null`, `undefined` or `[]`?

Comment: @martin any of this value could be great...the problem is when length > 0 it does not return anything

Comment: But it doesn't return anything only for this `server`. Your problem is when nothing in `getState().servers` passes the `filter`? Or you problem is that when `server.apps.length === 0` you want to pass `undefined`?

Comment: when server.apps.length === 0 it works normally, when it is > 0 I'd like to return null or undefined

Comment: right after that you have two `mergeMap`s where both will fail when you pass `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

RxJS's `filter` filters out the values from the pipe, so if `server.apps.length != 0` the value wont 'go' further to the `take(1)` and then to `subscribe()`. 
You can use `map(server => server.apps.length == 0? server: null)`

<strike>EDIT: `subscribe()` don't take second function attribute. To catch errors use RxJS's operator `catchError()` in the pipe.</strike>

Comment: I don't believe your edit is correct - it is perfectly acceptable to catch errors using a second function parameter to the subscribe call. Other than that, this is the correct answer to the problem.

Comment: I've just looked into RxJS Docs, and you're right. My bad :(